# The mage/cookies module has problems with full page cache

Tags: magento-2.0, full-page-cache, cookie

**Magento 2.0.12**

I have a widget that depends on `mage/cookies`, so I have:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    'jquery/ui',
    "mage/cookies"

], function($){

    // Some stuff

});
```

Everything works fine until I add an item to cart. When I do it Magento set the `private_content_version` cookie my widget stops working. It does nothing more, it doesn't pass for any function, it's as if there is nothing in the callback.

The widget returns to work if:

- I remove the cookie
- I remove "mage/cookies" dependency from my definition function
- I disable the cache

None of the three things are fine to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the `mage/cookies` and use like this sample.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'jquery/jquery.cookie'
    ], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var check_cookie = $.cookie('foo'); // Get Cookie Value
            var date = new Date();
            var minutes = 60;
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
            $.cookie('foo', '', {path: '/', expires: -1}); // Expire Cookie
            $.cookie('foo', 'bar', {expires: date}); // Set Cookie Expiry Time
            $.cookie('foo', 'setvalue'); // Set Cookie Value
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't know there was also jquery cookie in Magento2. It works! Thanks so much